# C# Selenium wait until element display is equal to none

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

So I'm trying to update a page using selenium which uses javascript, problem is the page its self uses javascript to prompt completion with a element that is always present, however when update isn't in process the style is set to

```
display: none;
```

How can I use (wait.Until) - Example

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("")));
```

on style changes?

So example

```
wait.Until(Display: Block; is true);
```

Html element is,

```
<example id="example" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">


</example>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wait for the [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) to change the element attribute as **`style="display: none;"`** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the [`InvisibilityOfElementLocated()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_InvisibilityOfElementLocated.htm) and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("element_id")));
```

Answer (score 0):

For C# you can follow below steps.

1. Download required package from NuGet using command

   Install-Package DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers -Version 3.11.0
2. For example you wants to choose suggestion from autocomplete textbox for term 'bubai'.
   Assume the seggestion is populated using ul and li.

a) To search from dubai send it to textbox using

```
  var txtSearch = driver.FindElements(By.Id("test_autocomplete")).FirstOrDefault();
        txtSearch.SendKeys("dubai");
```

b) Now make sure ul element is available/visible

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(
 SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("ul-id")));
```

c) Then check and click if a suggestion is populated

```
   string XpathForLi = "//*[@id='ul-id']/li[1]";

   new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(XpathForLi))).Click();
```